# How do you delete an empty array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, destructor, delete-operator

I am trying to create a constructor that deletes a directory objects name, then the subdirectories within the directory, and finally the directory itself. The `delete [] *subDirectories` line however causes segfaults whenever used.

Subdirectories are allocated by

```
subDirectories[subDirectoryCount++] = new Directory(arguments[1], umask, time, this); 

Directory::~Directory()
{
    delete [] name;

    for (int i = 0; i < subDirectoryCount; i++)
       delete subDirectories[i];
    delete [] *subDirectories;
}
```

Comment: `delete [] subDirectories`. Make sure `subDirectories` was created with `new[]`, otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: If it's C++ should definitively avoid C style array and use std containers like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 6):

Write:

```
delete [] subDirectories;
```

Make sure `subDirectories` is allocated using `new []`.

Anyway, stop doing that either. Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Directory>>` instead, Or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Directory>>` if the elements are to be shared. Either way let the library manage memory for you.